# Place ajax $get() into a javascript variable

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, razor

I need to place the result of an ajax get into a javascript variable.

The following works

```
$.get('@Url.Action("_Edit", "News", null)/' + guid_News, function (html)
{
    $("#divEdit").html(html);
});
```

This does not work

```
var editHtml = "";
$.get('@Url.Action("_Edit", "News", null)/' + guid_News, function (html)
{
    editHtml= html;
});
$("#divEdit").html(editHtml);
```

Have also tried

```
var editHtml = "";
editHtml = $.get('@Url.Action("_Edit", "News", null)/' + guid_News, function (html)
{
    return html;
});
$("#divEdit").html(editHtml);
```

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never tried using `@Url.Action` inside an `$.ajax` call (so I'm not 100% sure it works), but you could try using it since it gives you a more granular approach to ajax requests. In the `success` callback, you could

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("_Edit", "News", null)/' + guid_News,
    type: 'GET',
    //async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        $('#divEdit').html(data);
    }
});
```

`$.ajax` options even accept a parameter named `async` which you can set to false per your comment in @aroth's answer.

Answer (score 2):

The reason this does not work:

```
var editHtml = "";
$.get('@Url.Action("_Edit", "News", null)/' + guid_News, function (html)
{
    editHtml= html;
});
$("#divEdit").html(editHtml);
```

...is because this part is a [function closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29):

```
function (html)
{
    editHtml= html;
}
```

It does not execute immediately, and it does not block execution of the statements that follow it.  It will be executed when the server returns its response to the request, but by that time, your `$("#divEdit").html(editHtml);` statement has already executed with `editHtml` set to an empty string.

This should work:

```
var editHtml = "";
$.get('@Url.Action("_Edit", "News", null)/' + guid_News, function (html) {
    editHtml= html;
    setDivHtml();
});

function setDivHtml() {
    $("#divEdit").html(editHtml);
}
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make it synchronous and to get the value in a variable?

Comment: @Valamas - Yes, check the documentation for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).  You just need to replace your `.get()` with a `.ajax()` and set the `async` option to `false`.