# I need to use a var outside of a get function in jQuery

Tags: jquery, scope

Consider this code snippet:

```
$('#selectone').change(function(){
    var amount;
    $.get('search.php', {search:'units'}, function(result){
        //this will return only one or zero for me.
        amount = result;
    })
    if(amount>0)
    {
        alert('This option has been selected, please select another one');
    }
})
```

My variable `amount` are coming always `undefined`.  How can this be fixed or refactored?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920445/place-ajax-get-into-a-javascript-variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is because the following code is running before the callback function in your `$.get()` request:

```
if(amount>0)
{
    alert('This option has been selected, please select another one');
}
```

AJAX calls are asynchronous, meaning that the code around them runs as the AJAX call awaits the response. So the `if(amount>0)` code is running before the AJAX callback fires (meaning that for your `if/then` statement `amount` will always equal `null`).

To do what you want I suggest putting that code inside the callback function for your `$.get()` request:

```
$('#selectone').change(function(){
    $.get('search.php', {search:'units'}, function(result){
        //this will return only one or zero for me.
        if(result>0)
        {
            alert('This option has been selected, please select another one');
        }
    });
});
```

**--Update--**

You can also make use of jQuery's `$.when()` method:

```
$('#selectone').change(function(){
    var amount;
    var jqXHR = $.get('search.php', {search:'units'}, function(result){
        //this will return only one or zero for me.
        amount = result;
    });
    $.when(jqXHR).then(function () {
        if(amount>0)
        {
            alert('This option has been selected, please select another one');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I can't, this $.get will only execute if another field has a value, and this "if(amount>0){}" will contain code to both situations. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GustavoMartins I updated my answer to provide a solution that is structured more like your code. I'd need to see your actual code to help any further.

Comment: That limitation can be worked around using Jasper's suggestion (you don't indicate what other conditions need to be met, so Jasper couldn't have provided code for them), so I'mma upvote it. Sounds like you just need another conditional inside your change function that checks if amount is already set (by another field?) or if it's already greater than zero.

Comment: Now worked perfectly.  Im sorry for my oblivion about another condition. But know was perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use it inside the success function? Would be the best way:

```
$('#selectone').change(function(){
 var amount;
    $.post({
        async : false, // this makes it possible
        url: 'search.php', 
        data: {search:'units'}, 
        success : function(result){
            //this will return only one or zero for me.
            amount = result;
        }
    });

    if(amount>0)
    {
        alert('This option has been selected, please select another one');
    }
})
```

Comment: This is the same as the question's code. `if(amount>0)` will be evaluated before `amount = result;` which means `amount` will always equal `null` for the if statement.

Comment: No, because I got async=false, so the code will be set and wait untill the ready function is completed, so it is possible to set values and use after the function.

Comment: Gotcha, just so people reading this know, that means that the browser will lock-up until the AJAX call is complete (which could be anywhere from 50ms to several seconds for a small response).

Comment: That's true, but the only way to do this without a $.when and outside a success function.